# Using ajax jquery for search form

Tags: python, jquery, django

I'm working on a Django project where I want to use ajax jquery to complete my search in my search form.
Tried everything, but it does not seem to work.
Pls, where have I missed it?
used this [tutorial](http://lalicode.com/post/5/)

```
views.py

import json

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['query']
            catid = form.cleaned_data['catid']
            if catid == 0:
                products = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
            else:
                products = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=query, category_id=catid)

            category = Category.objects.all()
            context = {
                'products': products,
                'category': category,
                'query': query,
            }
            return render(request, 'shop/product/search.html', context)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


def search_auto(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        products = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
        results = []
        for pl in products:
            product_json = {}
            product_json = pl.name
            results.append(product_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

```js
<script>
$(function() {$("#query").autocomplete({
url: "{% url 'shop:search_auto' %}",
select: function (event, ui) {AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)},
minLength: 2,
});
});
function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
{var selectedObj = ui.item;}
</script>
```

`path('search', views.search_auto, name='search_auto'),`
Thanks.

Comment: it needs your js code and maybe your urls.py as well

Comment: it's complaining too much code

Comment: @ François Fournier
i've added it